# Pencil of curves of degree $d$ on $\Bbb{P}^2$ has $d^2$ base points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, projective-space

Let $\Bbb{P}^2$ be the projective plane over $\Bbb{C}$.

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a pencil of curves with degree $d$ on $\Bbb{P}^2$ with no fixed components.

Does $\mathcal{L}$ have necessarily $d^2$ base points (counted with multiplicity)?

Here's my attempt to prove this:

Take two distinct curves on $\mathcal{L}$ defined by homogeneous polynomials $F,G\in\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$. The set $S:=\{sF+tG=0\}_{(s:t)\in\Bbb{P}^1}$ defines a pencil without fixed components and with $F\cdot G=d^2$ base points, counted with multiplicity. I'm tempted to say that $\mathcal{L}=S$, but I don't know how to formalize this.

Comment: You can think of the base locus of a pencil as the scheme-theoretic intersection of its generating curves, which must have length $d^2$. As for the matter of identifying $\mathcal L$ with $S$, that depends on what precisely you mean by pencil (i.e. the set of curves, or the total space + the map to $\mathbb P^1$, or the $2$-dimensional subspace of $H^0(\mathbb P^2, \mathcal O(d))$,...).

Comment: @TabesBridges, I didn't know the definition in terms of a subspace of $H^0(\Bbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(d))$. That was very clarifying, thank you

Comment: Cool, I'll record it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pencil (or linear system in general) has a number of equivalent definitions, one of which is that the parametrizing $\mathbb P^1$ is $\mathbb P(V)$ for $V \subset H^0(\mathbb P^2, \mathcal O(d))$ a two-dimensional subspace. Any two non-proportional sections $F,G \in V$ span, and we can take their scheme-theoretic intersection as the definition of base locus, and its length (i.e. the number of base points with multiplicity) is $d^2$.